# How to run python code using Android kotlin code

Tags: python, android

I am  trying to read python code using android kotlin code .This is my python code

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO("file:///android_asset/YoloV8_model.pt")
def detectOCR(imagePath):
    try:
        results = model(imagePath)
        df = pd.DataFrame(results[0].boxes.data)
        df.sort_values(by=[0], inplace=True)
        df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

        output = ""
        kwh = False
        names = results[0].names

        for i in range(len(df)):
            if names[int(df[5][i])] == "kwh":
                kwh = True
                continue
            output += names[int(df[5][i])]
        if kwh:
            output += " kwh"
        return json.dumps({"status": "success", "msg": "successfully processed", "result": output})
    except:
        return "error"
```

this how i am trying to install python library .

all library installed but when i build code i am getting cpp related error

CMake Error at /private/var/folders/f1/bdvrvq0j1tsfylmfwl7pbb680000gn/T/pip-build-env-yi3y8_5d/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:49 (message):
Could not find compiler set in environment variable CC:
Chaquopy_cannot_compile_native_code.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE)

Please help me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

To run Python code in Kotlin I believe you have the necessary chaquo dependency, if so then you can import the Python module in your Kotlin code and execute the Python functions as shown below.

In your case, "your_python_module" should be the name of the Python file (without the .py extension) where you have defined the detectOCR function and other related code. If your Python code is in a file named ocr_utils.py, for example, then "your_python_module" should be replaced with "ocr_utils".
Here's an example of how you might call the detectOCR function from a Python module named ocr_utils.py:

```kotlin
import com.chaquo.python.Python

fun detectOCR(imagePath: String): String {
    val python = Python.getInstance()
    val module = python.getModule("ocr_utils")

    try {
        val results = module.callAttr("detectOCR", imagePath).toJava(JSONObject::class.java)
        return results.toString()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return "error"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution but this i am already doing here there is no problem problem is in install the library i also  have use chaquo same . there is issue with install library 
from ultralytics import YOLO
 please help me in this